# Failed to open the visio diagram on visio 2013

Tags: visio

We have generated UML diagram programmatically in java and it works fine with visio 2003 and 2010. But when we try to open the same file on visio 2013, we see below error.

***This UML Model Diagram was created with a feature that is not supported in this version of Visio***

If we do save as of same file from visio 2010 and open it in visio 2013, we dont see any issue. When I tried to compare the XML content of both, original and saved as version, there are some differences but I couldnt find the root cause of the issue.

Plesae suggest on how to proceed with this debugging. Any help in identifying the root cause and fix would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The issue most probably is that UML addon was discontinued in Visio 2013. Have you tried to click the error message (it is clickable, and when clicked, it shows the explanation?) It's odd that saving file in Visio 2010 fixes the issue - the UML addon just does not exist anymore in Visio 2013. (Can you probably post both files?)

Comment: Hi @Nikolay, thank you very much for your reply. The files are very large in content. Could you please share your mail id so that I can share them over mail ?

Comment: Exposing emails and PM is not allowed / not supported on SO. Maybe you can just attach files (or links to those files) to the post (or try specialized Visio-related forum, such as visguy)? Anyways if they are like 10Mb each then it's hard to tell. Again, are you sure you that saving the file using Visio 2010 "fixes" the issue (it should not?).

Comment: Hi @Nikolay,thanks for the reply. I have shared the files here [link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BzWtRHLR_GAcU0JxMmx3WEVNR1E&usp=sharing
). Please check them once let me know if you find any hint on the issue.

Comment: I get the warning message on both files in Visio 2013, and it says exactly that - UML *modeling* addon is not supported anymore. See more information here (since it's a marketing article, it's a bit hard to figure that out, but basically it says that UML and Database modeling diagrams were discontinued in Visio 2013): https://blogs.office.com/2012/10/17/uml-and-database-diagrams-in-the-new-visio/

Comment: Hi @Nikolay, do you see both the diagrams properly or the original one as jumbled (or incomplete) ? When we view them in Visio 2013 viewer, we dont see the original one properly. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: The first one looks jumbled (tried with Visio 2013)

Comment: Per https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Compatibility-between-different-versions-of-Visio-e17862db-a502-47a7-85dd-194fdfde67d2 please open in `Visio 2010` and post what `File` > `Info` > `Check Compatibility` says.  Also please try opening in compatibility mode in `Visio 2016` and let us know if that works.